# lib not found (ncurses)

Tags: c++, g++, ncurses

I'm trying to compile this c++ project: https://github.com/YvesZHI/FallingCode

I've successfully compiled it on my Mac OS, however, when I try to compile it on my ubuntu16.04, I get errors as below:

> undefined reference to 'initscr'
>   ...

which means that it can't find libncurses.

I've done: `apt install libncurses-dev`

I execute: `pkg-config --cflags --libs ncurses` and get the result:
`-D_GNU_SOURCE -lncurses -ltinfo`

`g++ --version` gives me

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0

I'm thinking if there is some error its makefile...

Comment: Yes the makefile's use of `cflags:= -Wall -lncurses -static-libstdc++` almost certainly puts `libncurses` in the wrong place - really IMHO one should use a separate `CFLAGS` for the compile phase and `LDFLAGS` or `LDLIBS` for the link phase

Comment: @steeldriver   Thanks dude, it works now. You can make an answer if you wish.

Comment: feel free to post your own solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @steeldriver, I use `LDLIBS` in makefile and it works now:

```
LDLIBS=-lncurses
```

Obviously ubuntu and mac are different on processing makefile.